# clang error is coming on runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, clang

I am working on app and suddenly prefix.pch file deleted automatically and 
this error comes:Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

i havn't found any working answer in google search.
Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem had to do with the Architecture settings on my sub projects. Xcode 4.2 changes the default Architecture to just armv7 instead of both armv6 and armv7. I had updated my main project to armv6 and armv7, but the sub-projects were still only using armv7. Once I updated all of the sub-projects then it started linking properly.